# LoadScene always works in Editor, but only on first play-through in Build: Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

LoadScene works in Unity Editor as expected.
In Build it loads Scenes 1, 2 & 3 correctly when desired, but won't load 1 or 2 again from 3.

Originally I had a few utility scripts as non-monobehaviour classes, with static functions. The SceneManagement script was one of these.
Everything worked (or didn't) as described in the above problem.

Everything worked as expected in Editor, but in Build, I could only get as far as scene 3 (EndMenu) and I couldn't return to scenes 1 or two (StartMenu and Match respectively)

I have just changed all my utility scripts to monobehaviour classes, and created a DDOL Gameobject in a PreLoad Scene and hung my utility scripts onto that. 
I had hoped that it was my lack of understanding of accessing non-mono classes that was causing an issue I hadn't experienced before.
Turns out my script is just as non-functional using all scripts in scenes.

```
LoadLevel.cs
Currently Monobehaviour script component on the DDOL Gameobject

public class LoadLevel : MonoBehaviour {

    public void LoadScene(int p_LevelIndex)
    {
        Debug.Log("Lead Level Called");
        SceneManager.LoadScene(p_LevelIndex, LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
}
```

```
EndGameMenu.cs
Component of the Canvas Object in the game-over screen

public class EndMenuFunctionality : MonoBehaviour {

    // This is how I grab the various Utility scrips from the DDOL gameobject
    // Non of the Errors register in-editor
    private void Awake()
    {
        GameObject singleton = GameObject.Find("Singleton");

        if (singleton != null)
        {
            loader = singleton.GetComponent<LoadLevel>();
            statCarrier = singleton.GetComponent<GameStatCarrier>();
            display = singleton.GetComponent<DisplayUtility>();
            readWrite = singleton.GetComponent<DataIO>();
        }
        else Debug.LogError("EndMenu Cannot Find Singleton Scripts!");

        AssignStatValuesToDisplay();
    }

    // I added these string additions to the Button Functions so i could see in the build which functions are called.
    public void OnPressNewGame()
    {
        noDataWarning.text += "New Game Press Registered @ End Menu";

        PushCurentStatsToLast();
        loader.LoadScene(2);
    }

    public void OnPressReturnToMain()
    {
        noDataWarning.text += "Return Press Registered @ End Menu";

        PushCurentStatsToLast();
        loader.LoadScene(1);
    }
}
```

Basically, when I had these Utility scripts as non-Monobehavious scripts and was accessing their static functions via 
ScriptName.FunctionName() 
OR 
as shown above with all scripts in-scene and creating object references, 
I do not understand why the LoadLevel script in the Build, loads:
(Preload.scene), StartMenu.scene, Match.scene and EndMenu.scene
but then refuses to load StartMenu.scene or Match.scene from EndMenu.scene.

It works just as expected in Editor.

If anyone can tell me what (doubtlessly simple) mistake I am overlooking, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you sure your loader script is in every scene? are you getting any errors? (this is when things like a singleton that persists over scenes can be useful)

Comment: Hey, yeah, in Editor (at least) the singleton I begrudgingly built is in every scene, and I get zero errors. Not even warnings.

Comment: hmm then you need to debug, throw a kajillion debug messages in and see where it gets to with what values

Answer (score 0):

HUZZAR!

It's my damnable DataIO script!

For some reason, my writing out of a Json file is blocking the continuation of the program!

I noticed that the Build version waits until the Play is Stopped before actually writing the file to disk...

SO I will go back to the drawing board for that script and see whether I can make this tiny test game Great Again ;)